# How to retrieve data from two tables by SQL in Nodejs

Tags: jquery, sql, node.js, backend

I have 2 tables: clientDevices and keyvalueTB

(1) clientDevices Table has Id, clientId, Dev, DeviceName

(2) keyvalueTB has Timestmp, Dev, temperature

I want to get the data of illumW and temperature where DeviceName = "Room 1"

My code is below

```
app.get('information', function(req, res){
    var room = 'Room 1';
    var query = connection.query ( 'SELECT keyvalueTB.illumW, keyvalueTB.temperature FROM keyvalueTB INNER JOIN clientDevices ON clientDevices.DevEUI = keyvalueTB.DevEUI WHERE clientDevices.DeviceName = "Room 1"');
    console.log(query);
    res.send(query);

});
console.log("Listening on port 8080");
app.listen(8080);
```

When I try to run it in the http://localhost:8080/information, the error messages display "Cannot GET /information" Anyone help!

Comment: I am not sure, what connection and underlying db you are using, but I am pretty sure, that query will be async (callback or promise based)

Comment: This looks like MySQL, in which case you would need to provide a second argument (callback) and call res.send or res.json there)

Comment: It is mySQL. Do you guys know how to retrieve information from keyvalueTB where the Timestmp is the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in the path, it should be:

```js
app.get('/information', function(req, res){
```

The error `Cannot GET /information` is thrown by Express. The path handler callback is not executed and so the query is also not executed.

Comment: got it. Thanks for your help!